# Issue with learndash custom taxonomy template name

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have some issue with Learndash custom taxonomy template name. I have this url: `http://example.com/course-category/photoshop/` and I want to have a custom template for `course-category` taxonomy. I name it `taxonomy-course-category.php` but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

course-category is the slug of your taxonomy 
You have to use the name that you registred your taxonomy with it instead
So the file must be similar to this
taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}.php